# Drag and Drop into Fabric.js canvas

Tags: drag-and-drop, fabricjs

How can I drop items (like image, or other object from other canvas) into canvas which is managed by fabricjs? I have found many examples how to move items inside canvas but I would like to drag and drop item from outer element into canvas.

Comment: The same way you would implement drag&drop functionality with HTML5/Javascript. Just use canvas as a drop target (and add objects onto Fabric canvas accordingly)

Comment: On printio.ru (which is behind fabric.js) the editor allows you to click an image (clipart) outside the fabric canvas, and then that clipart piece appears on the canvas, and you can edit it, and right-click to select to delete. It's different from drap-and-drop onto the canvas, but gives a very similar functionality and may be easier to maintain? Just food for thought.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Since you asked for an example and I haven't tried it out myself yet, here goes:

## [Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/natchiketa/w8kkc/)

---

## Markup

```html
<div id="images">
    <img draggable="true" src="http://i.imgur.com/8rmMZI3.jpg" width="250" height="250"></img>
    <img draggable="true" src="http://i.imgur.com/q9aLMza.png" width="252" height="295"></img>
    <img draggable="true" src="http://i.imgur.com/wMU4SFn.jpg" width="238" height="319"></img>
</div>

<div id="canvas-container">
    <canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="600"></canvas>
</div>
```

## JS Breakdown

### 1. `Fabric.canvas` instance

First we want our canvas, of course:

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
```

### 2. Feature Detection (optional)

Not sure this is necessary, since the fact that you have a canvas makes it very likely that the browser has Drag and Drop as well. Were you to use it, you can do so like this, using [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/):

```js
if (Modernizr.draganddrop) {
    // Browser supports HTML5 DnD.

    // Bind the event listeners for the image elements

    // Bind the event listeners for the canvas
} else {
    // Replace with a fallback to a library solution.
    alert("This browser doesn't support the HTML5 Drag and Drop API.");
}
```

### 3. Events

Again, unlike the source article I below, the source and target elements are different (in that articles's example, you just move `div`s around within the same parent container), so I failed to notice that some of the events are meant for the element being dragged, but most are bound to the element into which you are dropping.

*NOTE: I know this is technically a question about Fabric.js, but it's really kind of a question about Drag and Drop in the context of adding objects to a `<canvas>` with Fabric.js, which is why I'm going a bit more in depth about the DnD stuff now.*

For the `<img>`

- `dragstart` (I added a class here to lower the opacity)
- `dragend` (and removed that class here)

For `#canvas-container`:

- `dragenter` (added a class to give the canvas container that nifty dotted line)
- `dragover`: Here you can set the `event.dataTransfer.dropEffect` property to show one of the native cursor types. The default would be `'move'` here, but I set it to `'copy'` since I don't actually remove the `<img>` element (in fact in the fiddle you can, for example create several [McClures](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=oC7TVRU5nho#t=2s)).
- `dragleave` (removed the dotted line here)
- `drop`: The handler for this event creates and adds the `fabric.Image` object (see the fiddle).

```js
if (Modernizr.draganddrop) {
    // Browser supports HTML5 DnD.

    // Bind the event listeners for the image elements
    var images = document.querySelectorAll('#images img');
    [].forEach.call(images, function (img) {
        img.addEventListener('dragstart', handleDragStart, false);
        img.addEventListener('dragend', handleDragEnd, false);
    });
    // Bind the event listeners for the canvas
    var canvasContainer = document.getElementById('canvas-container');
    canvasContainer.addEventListener('dragenter', handleDragEnter, false);
    canvasContainer.addEventListener('dragover', handleDragOver, false);
    canvasContainer.addEventListener('dragleave', handleDragLeave, false);
    canvasContainer.addEventListener('drop', handleDrop, false);
} else {
    // Replace with a fallback to a library solution.
    alert("This browser doesn't support the HTML5 Drag and Drop API.");
}
```

Sources:

- [HTML5 Rocks - Native HTML5 Drag and Drop](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/dnd/basics/)
- [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/)
- [Web Platform Docs > DOM > Properties - dropEffect](http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/dom/properties/dropEffect)
- [Web Platform Docs > DOM > Events](http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/dom/events)

  - [dragstart](http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/dom/events/dragstart)
  - [dragend](http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/dom/events/dragend)
  - [dragenter](http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/dom/events/dragenter)
  - [dragover](http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/dom/events/dragover)
  - [dragleave](http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/dom/events/dragleave)
  - [drop](http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/dom/events/drop)

Comment: can we do drag and drop from desktop to canvas using above code as I tried but cudn't do it

Comment: Try it out in the fiddle (the big link at the beginning of my answer). It works there—the code included in the answer is not all of the code.

Comment: I have tried the code but I am confused that from above code how we can drag and drop from desktop to canvas because we have to mention in script that we are dragging from desktop

Comment: I'm sorry, I misread your initial comment. The HTML5 Drag and Drop API is for making DOM elements draggable and droppable within the DOM. Dragging files from the desktop into the browser is a different thing, for which you'd use something like the Filesystem API. See this different HTML5 Rocks article for details: http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/08/Integrating-input-type-file-with-the-Filesystem-API

Comment: I have adapted this dragnDrop code for my fabricjs page - works fine in chrome but not in firefox... I do have the - if (e.stopPropagation) in the handleDrop(e) and also the - if (e.preventDefault) in the handleDragOver(e)

Comment: I have adapted this dragnDrop code for my fabricjs page - works fine in chrome but not in firefox..  Still looking for a solution for firefox  I saw another post regarding Firefox and he said : Firefox requires that a user run the dataTransfer.setData function in the event.For you jQuery users, that means the following code should resolve your issue:
function dragstartHandler(event){
  event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', 'anything');
}
Future events on the same drag will now properly fire as you expected. Obviously you can replace the setData arguments with more useful data.

Comment: @natchiketa Sorry for reviving an old thread but. Why does the fiddle not work anymore? And also fabricjs 'canvas-container' is a class not an id as of the latest fabricjs. Can you fix your code please so I could use it? Thanks!

Answer (score 17):

I had gone through fiddle of @natchiketa, And fixed the problem , just check this fiddle..

http://jsfiddle.net/Ahammadalipk/w8kkc/185/

```
    window.onload = function () {

        var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');

        /* 
        NOTE: the start and end handlers are events for the <img> elements; the rest are bound to 
        the canvas container.
        */

        function handleDragStart(e) {
            [].forEach.call(images, function (img) {
                img.classList.remove('img_dragging');
            });
            this.classList.add('img_dragging');
        }

        function handleDragOver(e) {
            if (e.preventDefault) {
                e.preventDefault(); 
            }

            e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'copy';
            return false;
        }

        function handleDragEnter(e) {                
            this.classList.add('over');
        }

        function handleDragLeave(e) {
            this.classList.remove('over'); 
        }

        function handleDrop(e) {               
            if (e.stopPropagation) {
                e.stopPropagation(); // stops the browser from redirecting.
            }

            var img = document.querySelector('#images img.img_dragging');

            var newImage = new fabric.Image(img, {
                width: img.width,
                height: img.height,
                // Set the center of the new object based on the event coordinates relative
                // to the canvas container.
                left: e.layerX,
                top: e.layerY
            });
            newImage.hasControls = newImage.hasBorders = false;
            canvas.add(newImage);

            return false;
        }

        function handleDragEnd(e) {
            // this/e.target is the source node.
            [].forEach.call(images, function (img) {
                img.classList.remove('img_dragging');
            });
        }

        if (Modernizr.draganddrop) {



            var images = document.querySelectorAll('#images img');
            [].forEach.call(images, function (img) {
                img.addEventListener('dragstart', handleDragStart, false);
                img.addEventListener('dragend', handleDragEnd, false);
            });

            var canvasContainer = document.getElementById("canvas-container");
            canvasContainer.addEventListener('dragenter', handleDragEnter, false);
            canvasContainer.addEventListener('dragover', handleDragOver, false);
            canvasContainer.addEventListener('dragleave', handleDragLeave, false);
            canvasContainer.addEventListener('drop', handleDrop, false);
        } else {

            alert("This browser doesn't support the HTML5 Drag and Drop API.");
        }
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for updating the jsfiddle It works in Chrome, but in Firefox, it opens the image in the browser, instead of on the canvas.

Comment: @AhammadaliPK's answer worked, excepted i needed to put a call to preventDefault in the handleDrop function to get it to work properly on firefox.

Comment: had not tested this on mobile devices , i think you have to listen touch events too.

Comment: Your JS fiddle doesn't drop in exact dropped location.

Answer (score 3):

Well, the question is quite old^^

I have updateted the fiddle, no it will work in Firefox as well.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w8kkc/486/)

```
function handleDrop(e) {
    // this / e.target is current target element.

    e.preventDefault(); //I've altert this line for FireFox
```

Comment: Would you update the code. None of these solutions work for me. I've been trying to get something that works for at least a week. I've copied the code exactly and it just doesn't work in testing with Safari or Chrome. I'd sure appreciate your help on this.Using Fabricjs 3.4.0.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer no longer works.

This is for drag and drop from desktop using the dataTransfer interface.

```
canvas.on('drop', function(event) {
    
    // prevent the file to open in new tab
    
    event.e.stopPropagation();
    event.e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    event.e.preventDefault();

    // Use DataTransfer interface to access the file(s)
    
    if(event.e.dataTransfer.files.length > 0){

        var files = event.e.dataTransfer.files;
        
        for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {

            // Only process image files.
            
            if (f.type.match('image.*')) {            
                
                // Read the File objects in this FileList.
                
                var reader = new FileReader();
                
                // listener for the onload event
                
                reader.onload = function(evt) {
                    
                    // put image on canvas
                    
                    fabric.Image.fromURL(evt.target.result, function(obj) {
                        
                        obj.scaleToHeight(canvas.height);
        
                        obj.set('strokeWidth',0);
                        
                        canvas.add(obj);       
                    
                    });
                };
               
                // Read in the image file as a data URL.
               
                reader.readAsDataURL(f);
            }
        }
    }  
});
```

**Resources**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API/File_drag_and_drop

Comment: Worked like a charm, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, drag and drop is not already provided by fabricjs,
fiddling it will be quite interesting.
Well I m new to javascript and fabricJS but I think this fiddle might help
[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Sahil999/rtbmy6hw/14/)

html code

```
<div class="img_cont">
        <img class="img" id="ele1" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragElement(event)" src="https://webkit.org/wp-content/uploads/STP-300x300.png"> 
        <img class="img" id="ele2" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragElement(event)" src="https://webkit.org/wp-content/uploads/ephy-webkit-graphic.png"> 
         <img class="img" id="ele3" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragElement(event)" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/css-tricks/image/upload/w_600,q_auto,f_auto/buysellads/uu/7/112766/1646327381-MC_CSSTricks_Logo_600x600-_1_.png">
         <img class="img" id="ele4" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragElement(event)" src="https://miro.medium.com/max/1400/1*9hd_8qR0CMZ8L0pVbFLjDw.png"> 
    </div>
    <br>
    <div id="canvas_cont" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ondrop="dropElement(event)">
        <canvas id="canvas" width="650" height="350" ></canvas>
    </div>
```

javascript code

```
// allowDrop function called on ondragover event.
function allowDrop(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
}
//dragElement function called on ondrag event.
function dragElement(e) {
  e.dataTransfer.setData("id", e.target.id); //transfer the "data" i.e. id of the target dragged.
}
//Initializing fabric canvas on window load event.
var canvas;
window.onload = function(){
    canvas = new fabric.Canvas(document.getElementById("canvas"));
}
//dropElement function called on ondrop event.
function dropElement(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var data = e.dataTransfer.getData("id"); //receiving the "data" i.e. id of the target dropped.
  var imag = document.getElementById(data); //getting the target image info through its id. 
  var img = new fabric.Image(imag, { //initializing the fabric image.
    left: e.layerX - 80,  //positioning the target on exact position of mouse event drop through event.layerX,Y.
    top: e.layerY - 40,
  });
  img.scaleToWidth(imag.width); //scaling the image height and width with target height and width, scaleToWidth, scaleToHeight fabric inbuilt function. 
  img.scaleToHeight(imag.height);
  canvas.add(img); 
}
```