# Perform a drag and drop with fabric.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm searching for a way to perform a drag and drop with fabric-js on a HTML canvas tag but I can't find any solutions. Please help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Drag and Drop into Fabric.js canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13868783/drag-and-drop-into-fabric-js-canvas)