# Cannot catch drag events in fabricjs

Tags: javascript, canvas, drag-and-drop, fabricjs

I'm trying to drop external div into fabricjs canvas. I know there is an answer [Drag and Drop into Fabric.js canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13868783/drag-and-drop-into-fabric-js-canvas), however it didn't work for me.

Here is basic thing I'm trying to do:

```
  let canvasContainer = document.getElementById('canvas')

  canvasContainer.addEventListener('dragenter', this.onDragEnter, false);
  canvasContainer.addEventListener('dragover',  this.onDragOver, false);
  canvasContainer.addEventListener('dragleave', this.onDragLeave, false);
  canvasContainer.addEventListener('drop',      this.onDrop, false);
```

But event handlers did not get executed.

I noticed very important thing: when I inspected DOM I found out there are two canvases: one with `canvas lower-canvas` and another one with `canvas upper-canvas` classes.

Only `lower-cavas` has `id="canvas"` property. When I deleted (manually through web inspector) upper-canvas div, event handlers did get executed.

Here how resulting HTML markup looks like:

```
<div class="canvas-container" style="width: 663px; height: 663px; position: relative; user-select: none;">
   <canvas data-v-346adb42="" id="canvas" class="canvas lower-canvas" width="1326" height="1326" style="position: absolute; width: 663px; height: 663px; left: 0px; top: 0px; touch-action: none; user-select: none;"></canvas>
   <canvas class="upper-canvas canvas" width="663" height="663" style="position: absolute; width: 663px; height: 663px; left: 0px; top: 0px; touch-action: none; user-select: none; cursor: default;"></canvas>
</div>
```

I'm not sure why there are two canvases. Even when I don't delete the upper-canvas, I still get green plus sign like my div is ready to be dropped.

Comment: Yes there is two canvases, make a minimal snippet stating your issue. for [events demo check](http://fabricjs.com/events)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/56370/ Here it is...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To bind eventlistners use `canvas.on(event,handler)`.

***DEMO***

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas')

canvas.on('dragenter', onDragEnter, false);
canvas.on('dragover',  onDragOver, false);
canvas.on('dragleave', onDragLeave, false);
canvas.on('drop',      onDrop, false);

function onDragEnter() {
  console.log('onDragEnter')
}

function onDragOver() {
  console.log('onDragOver')
}

function onDragLeave() {
  console.log('onDragLeave')
}
function onDrop() {
  console.log('onDrop')
}
```

```css
#canvas {
  background-color: green;
}

#draggable {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.2.3/fabric.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <canvas id="canvas" width=200 height=200></canvas>
  <div id="draggable" draggable="true">
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/56610/).

Comment: use width and height inside canvas tag, don't by css.