# fabricjs - dragging images to the canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, fabricjs

I have the following fiddle where I'm trying to drag images onto another image that's loaded on a canvas.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uw1L0t3x/)

The "picture" image will originally be loaded on the canvas. I'd like to drag the "Sticker" image onto the canvas, after that I'd like to be able to resize and rotate.

My last attempt was without FabricJS and with vanilla JS, for example:

```
function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    startOffsetX = ev.offsetX;
    startOffsetY = ev.offsetY;
    var dropX = ev.clientX - canvasLeft - startOffsetX;
    var dropY = ev.clientY - canvasTop - startOffsetY;
    var id = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
    var dropElement = document.getElementById(id);
    ctx.drawImage(dropElement, dropX, dropY);
    var cloneImg = new Image();
    cloneImg.src = dropElement.src;
    boxes.push({
        img: cloneImg,
        x: dropX,
        y: dropY,
        w: 100,
        h: 100
    });
}
```

However this only loaded the "sticker" into the canvas and I didn't get much further, it's a lot of work involved and that's why I'm trying to use a library now.

I been trying to do this with FabricJS but I haven't succeeded, and I'm pretty lost. The documentation is long and very detailed yet I can't figure it out for what I need it with.

How can I do this?

Comment: If you can bear to switch library to the Konvajs HTML5 canvas lib...your have two challenges, first to drag and drop the sticker, then to transform it via rotate & resize.  The drag-drop is quite simple, and there is a transformer class that can handle that part. The konvajs library is quite approachable and the support very good here on SO and on the Git chat. See https://konvajs.github.io/docs/index.html

Comment: Thanks @VanquishedWombat can you show me how i'd work with it using my fiddle?

Comment: Not at the moment but there are plenty of examples on the Konvajs site. Look here for the transformer: https://konvajs.github.io/docs/select_and_transform/Basic_demo.html, meanwhile draggable is a standard attribute of objects in konvajs so you can ignore that and look at https://konvajs.github.io/docs/shapes/Image.html which will show how to make an image and load it.

Comment: Are you using version 1.7.xx or 2+??

Comment: Durga right now the fiddle has 1.7, but I can use 2 as well.

Comment: There is a solution at this ==> https://stackoverflow.com/a/35194849/9412410